# Scala ignore exception when promise is completed multiple times

Tags: scala, exception, promise

i am working on promises that may be written on more than one place. Since scala throws an exception when trying to complete a promise that was already completed i was thinking on ignoring the exception. To promote good quality code i was thinking on improving the way i do it.

First i wrote the generic method (in my case it returns Unit but i may transform it into T)

```
def ignoreException(closure: () => Unit): Unit = {
  try {
    closure()
  } catch {
    case _ => {} // ignore
  }
}
```

And the promise statement should look like:

```
ignoreException {promise failure(new Exception)}
```

But sadly i can only get it to work like this:

```
ignoreException {() => promise failure(new JException) }
```

How can i get this to work using the first way?

Comment: You can use `tryComplete`, `trySuccess` and `tryFailure` to try completing a promise without throwing if it has already completed.

Comment: Lee Thanks man. I should have known. Once again scala did not fail me. I am curious to the solution to my problem still since it could apply to another cases but for now you saved me :D

Comment: @Lee you should add that as an answer I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tryComplete`, `trySuccess` and `tryFailure` to try complete a promise without throwing exceptions if it has already completed:

```
val completed: Boolean = promise tryFailure(new Exception)
val completed: Boolean = promise trySuccess("value")
val completed: Boolean = promise tryComplete(Failure(new JException))
```